# Node - Abstracting Pipe Steps into Function

Tags: node.js, stream, pipe, node.js-stream, through2

I'm familiar with Node streams, but I'm struggling on best practices for abstracting code that I reuse a lot into a single pipe step.

Here's a stripped down version of what I'm writing today:

```
inputStream
.pipe(csv.parse({columns:true})
.pipe(csv.transform(function(row) {return transform(row); }))
.pipe(csv.stringify({header: true})
.pipe(outputStream);
```

The actual work happens in `transform()`. The only things that really change are `inputStream`, `transform()`, and `outputStream`. Like I said, this is a stripped down version of what I actually use. I have a lot of error handling and logging on each pipe step, which is ultimately why I'm try to abstract the code.

What I'm looking to write is a single pipe step, like so:

```
inputStream
.pipe(csvFunction(transform(row)))
.pipe(outputStream);
```

What I'm struggling to understand is how to turn those pipe steps into a single function that accepts a stream and returns a stream. I've looked at libraries like through2 but I'm but not sure how that get's me to where I'm trying to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I ended up going with. I used the [through2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/through2) library and the [streaming API of the csv library](http://csv.adaltas.com/csv/examples/) to create the pipe function I was looking for.

```
var csv = require('csv');
    through = require('through2');

module.exports = function(transformFunc) {
    parser = csv.parse({columns:true, relax_column_count:true}),
    transformer = csv.transform(function(row) {
        return transformFunc(row);
    }),
    stringifier = csv.stringify({header: true});

    return through(function(chunk,enc,cb){
        var stream = this;

            parser.on('data', function(data){
                transformer.write(data);
            });

            transformer.on('data', function(data){
                stringifier.write(data);
            });

            stringifier.on('data', function(data){
                stream.push(data);
            });

            parser.write(chunk);

            parser.removeAllListeners('data');
            transformer.removeAllListeners('data');
            stringifier.removeAllListeners('data');
            cb();
    })
}
```

It's worth noting the part where I remove the event listeners towards the end, this was due to running into memory errors where I had created too many event listeners. I initially tried solving this problem by listening to events with `once`, but that prevented subsequent chunks from being read and passed on to the next pipe step.

Let me know if anyone has feedback or additional ideas.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `PassThrough` class like this:

```
var PassThrough = require('stream').PassThrough;

var csvStream = new PassThrough();
csvStream.on('pipe', function (source) {
  // undo piping of source
  source.unpipe(this);
  // build own pipe-line and store internally
  this.combinedStream =
    source.pipe(csv.parse({columns: true}))
      .pipe(csv.transform(function (row) {
        return transform(row);
      }))
      .pipe(csv.stringify({header: true}));
});

csvStream.pipe = function (dest, options) {
  // pipe internal combined stream to dest
  return this.combinedStream.pipe(dest, options);
};

inputStream
  .pipe(csvStream)
  .pipe(outputStream);
```

Comment: How would I pass the transform(row) reference into the stream? Wouldn't I be better off using a transform stream? I read that PassThrough is more for monitoring a stream than actually doing work on it?

Comment: Depends on how you package your stream handling. Simply put the function in a place where it's visible or hand it in as a reference. And of course you can implement your solution in a transform stream (have a look here https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_implementing_a_transform_stream). Showing the idea with a PassThrough stream was just the simplest way I found.